# Radius vs speed for flywheel energy storage

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum

If I understand the formula correctly, the equation for kinetic energy of a flywheel is $mw^2r^2$ whereas the formula for "centrifugal force" is $mw^2r$.

So how come so much focus is on the speed of flywheels if you could get 4x the power with only 2x the strain by doubling the radius?

Comment: How about the space required? And the bursting forces...

Comment: @SolarMike Grid sotrage doesnt really need to worry about space. Also how would bursting forces be a problem? Nothing is packing inside anything else

Comment: Have a search for "kinetic energy storage" and see what you find...

Comment: Yeah, no references to bursting forces and space requirements for portabpe use but not grid storage. I think you may be confused

Comment: I’m not confused, you don’t mention grid storage in your question and I know how kinetic energy storage works and it has been used on buses... So I’m happy where I am, I tried to help you by giving you some hints on what to search for to help your google-fu but....

Comment: And if rotating flywheels were so good, why would they look at dams, and refillable lakes for energy storage? What do you think about maintenance issues? Magneto-dynamic bearings?

Comment: @SolarMike most dams were either built ages ago or are huge and awful for the environment. Reservoirs are good but space inefficient and flywheels are better for the environment and space than moat other grid storage. I asked a question which was quite simple but you are not helping anyone. I simply wanted to know from someone who knows about the subject why there is more of a focus on speed than size when size from what ive seen has far less stress on the ring for the same energy.

Comment: The question you asked was too broad as you did not and still have not specified grid storage, so the questions I asked in my first comment were relevant. I have calculated things like this before, it is a common exercise given to engineers...

Answer (score 4):

While the kinetic energy scales with $r^2$, so does the material requirement. This means the kinetic energy storage only increases linearly with the amount of material. On the other hand running your flywheel faster increases kinetic energy storage for free (as long as you don't reach the stress limit). This means to keep cost low you always run your flywheel at maximum speed (for its radius). Then you either increase the flywheels radius or the amount of flywheels until you meet your required energy capacity. In both cases stored energy scales linearly with material requirement.

Comment: Thanks explains it. So it essentially does increase by square of radius as circumference increases linearly with radius

Comment: @P.Lord The energy capacity increases only by $r^2$ if you keep $\omega$ constant. But if your flywheel is already running at maximum speed, increasing $r$ while keeping $\omega$ constant will rip it apart. Therefore if you further increase $r$ you have to decrease $\omega$, to not rip it apart. The result is that the energy capacity only increases proportional to the mass $m$ for any flywheel. For a ring shaped flywheel that means $E\propto r$, for a disc shaped flywheel $E\propto r^2$.